# Помогите составить правильное регулярное выражение

Tags: php, регулярные-выражения

собственно вот регулярка

```
preg_match('%^(\w+)(/(\w+)+[+'])?$%', $pathInfo, $matches)
```

вот что пытаюсь поймать

```
serials/mulʹtfilʹm
```

Comment: `'%^(\w+)/([\wʹ]+)?$%'`, если парсер сломает кавычку - замените ее сами. [Пример работы](https://regex101.com/r/hG7iB5/1)

Comment: @MiKeBu не обижайтесь но вместо ответа просто попробуйте здесь http://www.phpliveregex.com/

Comment: Пожалуйста) ваш сервис тоже корректное выдает - http://www.phpliveregex.com/p/g4M

Comment: точно выдает а что это за знак ?

Comment: это та странная кавычка, которую я из `mulʹtfilʹm` скопировал. Может быть у вас кавычки были похожие, а коды юникода были разные

Comment: @MiKeBu формируйте ответ я подтвержу

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Решение

Поиск примет вид:

```
preg_match('%^(\w+)/([\wʹ]+)?$%', $pathInfo, $matches)
```

Изменение - вторая часть состоит из набора указанных символов, куда явно прописали нужные спец-символы.

### Примеры работы

[regex101](http://regex101.com/r/hG7iB5/1), [phpliveregex](http://www.phpliveregex.com/p/g4M)